# Why does a datepicker created on a detached div have zero height in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-ui-datepicker

When creating a jQuery UI datepicker on a detached div it works fine in Firefox but in Chrome it gets zero height.

```
$('<div/>').datepicker().appendTo('#some-element');
```

When attaching the div to the document first it works fine:

```
$('<div/>').appendTo('#some-element').datepicker();
```

However, since the actual code is not that simple (lots of legacy code, so attaching the div before creating its contents is difficult) I'm looking for a solution where the datepicker works even when created on a detached div.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/ZM95R/

Comment: According to someone in #jqueryui-dev it also doesn't work in IE8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug has been fixed

http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7552

and will be in the 1.8.15 release of jQuery UI